# JUnit Test with Mockito won't throw JSONException

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I'm currently struggling with getting my test to work.

I have a method a:

```
public void a(String test){
   b(test);
}
```

method b:

```
private void b(String test){
 try{
   JSONObject jsonObject=c(test);
   System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
 } catch (JSONException e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
```

and method c, which generates the JSONObject:

```
private JSONObject c(String test) throws JSONException{
  return new JSONObject().put("test",test);
}
```

I want to trigger the JSONException, but for some reason it won't. This is my code so far:

```
  @Test
  void aTest(){
    ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));

    TestClass testClass=new TestClass(this.getClass().getName());

    JSONObject jsonObject = Mockito.mock(JSONObject.class);
    Mockito.when(jsonObject.put(anyString(),anyString())).thenThrow(new JSONException("MalformedJSON"));



    testClass.a("Test");

    assertTrue(outContent.toString().contains("MalformedJSON"));

  }
```

I want the exception to be printed to the console, it works with other methods, but not for the JSONException. Always telling me that the Assertion is false. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Although you mocked the `JSONObject` and defined the behavior in your test, when you actually run `c()` you create a new `JSONObject`. This is a different object from your `jsonObject` you created in the JUnit Test. That's why your `Mockito.when(...)` configuration won't do anything.

Comment: I see, thanks. what would a possible workaround look like? Can't seem to find anything on the internet.

Comment: There is a tricky way to do that, With powermockito you can Mock the constructor ` PowerMockito.whenNew(A.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockOfA)`  and then ` Mockito.when(mockOfA.put(anyString(),anyString())).thenThrow(new JSONException("MalformedJSON"));` but you are forcing a cas that is not going to happen because that put just going to fail if the `new JSONObject ()` is null.

Comment: What I think you could do is `Mockito.spy()` your `TestClass`, and just make your call to method `c()` throw the Exception via Mockito. Would that work for you?